# primeng p-dropdown on a dynamic row

Tags: angular, dropdown, primeng

I have a p-dropdown that displays a list of select items that are generated in the component.
If I place the p-dropdown on the page as just a static input then it renders the list of the select items without issue.

**The intention is to include the p-dropdown in a row of cells**. So that rows can be added that contain the p-dropdown, or removed. This is rendered with an ngFor loop.  So I have an array of object, one of the object properties is a selected value of the p-dropdown.

If I start with an empty array, so the p-dropdown is not rendendered on the page, and then add an empty object to the ngFor array, this renders the p-dropdown in the row, **there are no values in the p-dropdown**. If just shows the select box and the place holder with no values to select from.

Why are the options not rendered when the p-dropdown is a part of an ngFor?  How can I do this?

Comment:  can you share some code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was the class on the div that represented the row that has an overflow:hidden applied. So the list was populated just not shown.